# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\androidWare\jdk1.7\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   My app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wjc.wjcrun"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
dependencies {
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1"
 }
```

Here is Project Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
   }
}
  allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your build.gradle like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wjc.wjcrun"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1"
 }
}
```